# Implementing popover controller in Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**Brief explanation:** Trying to implement popover controller on `home.html` page. Trying to follow the documentation but still unable to get through.

I have created `popover.ts` page beside `home.ts` but when I am trying to import in `home.ts` , it is saying `Cannot find module 'popover'`.

What am I doing wrong ?

**home.ts**

```
import { PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PopoverPage } from 'popover';

    @Component({})
    class MyPage {
      constructor(public popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {}

      presentPopover(myEvent) {
        let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPage);
        popover.present({
          ev: myEvent
        });
      }
    }
```

**popover.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
    template: `
      <ion-list>
        <ion-list-header>Ionic</ion-list-header>
        <button ion-item (click)="close()">Learn Ionic</button>
        <button ion-item (click)="close()">Documentation</button>
        <button ion-item (click)="close()">Showcase</button>
        <button ion-item (click)="close()">GitHub Repo</button>
      </ion-list>
    `
  })
  class PopoverPage {
    constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

    close() {
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this one

**home.ts**

```
import { PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PopoverPage } from './popover';

    @Component({})
 export class MyPage {
      constructor(public popoverCtrl: PopoverController) {}

      presentPopover(myEvent) {
        let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverPage);
        popover.present({
          ev: myEvent
        });
      }
    }
```

**popover.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
    template: `
      <ion-list>
        <ion-list-header>Ionic</ion-list-header>
        <button ion-item (click)="close()">Learn Ionic</button>
        <button ion-item (click)="close()">Documentation</button>
        <button ion-item (click)="close()">Showcase</button>
        <button ion-item (click)="close()">GitHub Repo</button>
      </ion-list>
    `
  })
  export class PopoverPage {
    constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}

    close() {
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    }
  }
```

Comment: please mask as a solution if it has resolved  your issue

Comment: [ts] Module '"f:/D/IONIC/experiments/myapp/src/pages/home/popover"' has no exported member 'PopoverPage'.